# Regex to check for specific pattern in String

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am tasked to use `regex` to verify a pattern in a string instead of using `substrings` due to accuracy reasons.

The `string` is as follows:

I need to verify that the `string` is in the format as **[GMT-CASE_<6 digits>]**.

---

A sample `string`:

> [GMT-CASE_000001] Query on...

May I know how can this be done?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean matching 6 digits? `\[GMT-CASE_[0-9]{6}]`

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes, matching 6 digits. my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\[GMT-CASE_[0-9]{6}\]
```

Explanation:

```
\[GMT-CASE_
```

This starts with the literal `[GMT-CASE_`. Since a square bracket has a special meaning in regular expressions you need to escape it with a backslash.

```
[0-9]{6}
```

Any character between 0 and 9, repeated 6 times.

```
\]
```

The closing bracket, again needed to be escaped.

Alternatively you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` for the digits. This would match non latin digits like the arabic `٦` as well.

Answer (score 1):

One possible answer would be `\[GMT-CASE_[0-9]{6}\]`

Check this https://regex101.com/r/tuDioP/1

Answer (score 0):

try to use the @ before the string
and the backslash before the brackets

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"\[GMT-CASE_[0-9]{6}\]");
Console.WriteLine(rx.IsMatch("[GMT-CASE_000001]"));
```

;
Use @ before to escape the \ behavior
also if u want just only one match its important to mention the begin and the end of the regex ^..$

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"^\[GMT-CASE_[0-9]{6}\]$");
```